# Reviewing uploaded images with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, upload

I am using PHP to upload images in my web application. The images are stored in some directory on the server while their paths are stored directly in MySQL database.

The upload goes very well and images get in the folder but the problem is accessing thoses images with their path field stored in the database : i am not yet able to find the correct form of the path i should use, now am using the realPath and dirname functions to help me get the path so finally an example of path is **C:\wamp\www\webroot\img.png** (since am on Windows using wampserver) So when i do something like :

```
  <img src="$image->path" />
```

i get no image shown in the browser and when i inspect it i get the expected code like :

```
 <img src="C:\wamp\www\webroot\img.png" />
```

which means that this path format is not correct to show the image.

I have tried many things : i took the same path and acced it with the browser and it showed me the image (with the file protocol automatically) so i  added **file://** to the image path but nothing was new. I have also tried to acces it as a web url and with that it goes will for example it shows the  image when putting

```
    localhost/webroot/img.png
```

But what i need exactly is being able to store and retrive the image file again. So is it a file system probelm ? is the code platform independant ?

I will be very grateful for any help

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't show an image with its path, but with its URL.

In PHP, we use to save the filename only in MySQL and after, you display the image with `<img src="path/to/img/<?php echo $image->filename; ?>" />`

That's all!

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it does not work with me because my problem is with the path part **path/to/img/**. It is not showing even i reference it very will.

Comment: Thank you again, i have found the answer :  the path worked finally because i was wrong when i said that i referenced it well actually it should be relative to some directory like a said in the answer  to the question. Thnk you @Raphael.

Answer (score 0):

Add the file protocal to your path.

```
<img src="file:///<?php echo $image->path; ?>" />.
```

The best thing you could have to done is save the image in a folder inside your project/website folder. Then save the path to the image from the root folder in the DB.

Example: I uploaded a an image of filename "image.png" inside "Img" folder in the Website Root Folder. Then I will save "Img/image.png" inside my DB.
So anytime I want to reference the image, I will just use

```
<img src="/<?php echo $image->path; ?>" />
```

Or

```
 <img src="<?php echo $image->path; ?>" />
```

Comment: Thank you @hardeshorlar for your answer, actually i did something similar to what you suggested, it is explained in my own answer as i found the solution. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting your time, i have solved the problem. It was an issue with how my application is accessed. It should be accessed from only a directory called **web** so every path should be referenced from that directory !!.